# Converting M/DD/YYY string to date in Crystal Report

Tags: string, date, crystal-reports

I need to convert submission date field saved as a string on the DB into a date field so I can filter a report by submission date. The data is saved in MM/DD/YYYY format without leading zeros for single digit months (ie 1/1/2015 for Jan) and some records don't have a date in them (either it's blank or there's a space in there). I added the leading zerosand fixed the empty records using this formula:

```
    local numbervar totalLength := 10;
    local numbervar dateLength := length({S85FLD.TEN_CUSTOM02});

    WhileReadingRecords;

    if totalLength=0 or isnull({S85FLD.TEN_CUSTOM02}) or {S85FLD.TEN_CUSTOM02}=" "
    then "01/01/2000" Else
    if dateLength < totalLength
    then "0"+{S85FLD.TEN_CUSTOM02}
    else {S85FLD.TEN_CUSTOM02}
```

I then removed the "/" with:

```
    EvaluateAfter ({@SubDate:Add"0"});

    Replace({@SubDate:Add"0"},"/","")
```

Now I'm trying to convert the string to a date with:

```
  EvaluateAfter ({@SubDate:Remove"/"});

  cdate (ToNumber (Right ({@SubDate:Remove"/"}, 4)),
  ToNumber (Left ({@SubDate:Remove"/"}, 2)),
  ToNumber (Mid ({@SubDate:Remove"/"}, 3, 2)))
```

I checked all the syntax and CR says it's fine. But when I go to preview the data or add the field to the filter I get "A day number must be between 1 and the number of days in the month." error. When I look at the original field all the MID values are within the day range of the month it's in. Any suggestions?

Software Version: SAP CR Developer 14

Comment: how does the output `({@SubDate:Add"0"})` looks like and `({@SubDate:Remove"/"});` looks like can you show example

Comment: Output for add "0" is 01/02/2015 (no change to double digit months) Output for remove "/" is 01022015.